# Azure QnA: Error "The scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region. Try selecting different region or scale option."

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I am creating Azure QnA service and I am getting below error message "The scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region. Try selecting different region or scale option."

I have Selected below options

- SKU :F0
- Location:westus
- SKU2: Free
- Search hosting mode : Default

Microsoft.Web/serverfarms

- Status: Unauthorized
- Provisioning: StateFailed

I am new to azure, appreciate your help

Comment: Which parts of that message are unclear?

Comment: Basically why I am getting this error. I am not able to create the QnA service in Azure. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the error tells you that some configuration is not available - isn't that pretty clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region" when create a function App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790218/error-scale-operation-is-not-allowed-for-this-subscription-in-this-region-when)