# Error "scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region" when create a function App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am running the various steps in Build a [serverless web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/functions/tutorial-static-website-serverless-api-with-database?tutorial-step=2) and am getting a "The scale operation is not allowed for this subscription in this region. Try selecting different region or scale option" error when "creating a function app". Both the resource group(first-serverless-app) and the storage account(meethagoelstorage) have been created in "west central us", I am trying to create a function app in "west central us" using the

```
az functionapp create -n meethagoelfunction2 -g first-serverless-app -s meethagoelstorage -c westcentralus
```

i am using the free 1 year azure subscription. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Free trial subscriptions are not allow to create Azure AppService and ServerLess in West Central US and Brazil South locations.   Do try other location instead.

Comment: Swapped to `West US` out of `West Central US` and it worked great! Where did you get this info?

Comment: `West Europe` also worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might also encounter this error when your subscription is hitting the limit on virtual CPUs, which by default is 20. You can create a support ticket to increase that limit.